# Socket server stops running upon client connecting

Tags: python, python-sockets

I'm building a chat room using socket library and threading. The server should let multiple clients connect while receiving data from each client and broadcasting it to all the other clients using threading.

After running the server, I run the client code but then my server stops running.

server.py

```py
import socket
import threading

host = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
port = 5000
client_conns = []

s = socket.socket()
s.bind((host, port))
s.listen(10)

def broadcast_msg(msg):
    for conn in client_conns:
        conn.send(msg)

def handle_client(conn, addr):
    while True:
        msg = conn.recv(4096).decode()
        broadcast_msg(msg)
        

while True:
    conn, address = s.accept()
    print(f"Connection from: {address}")
    clients.append(conn)

    threading._start_new_thread(handle_client, (conn, address))
```

client.py

```py
import socket

def client():
    host = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
    port = 5000

    s = socket.socket()
    s.connect((host, port))

    alias = input("Alias: ")

    while True:
        message = input(f"{alias}: ")
        message = alias + ": " + message
        s.send(message.encode())

        data = s.recv(4096).decode()
        print(data)

client()
```

Comment: your socket initilization is wrong 
for an IPV4, TCP socket you have to write **socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)**

Comment: Thank you, but what is the default if I do not specify that?

Comment: @X-_-FARZA_D-_-X - I don't see anything hinting that OP wants datagrams. I think this are TCP sockets, the default.

Comment: The defaults are `socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM`, so that isn't your problem (run `s=socket.socket()`, then inspect `s.family` and `s.type` and compare those values to `socket.AF_INET` and `socket.SOCK_STREAM`).

Comment: Must I add it to the server and client code? For now I only added it to the server, and the server still closes when a client tries to connect

Comment: How do you run the server? Are any messages showing up on its stderr?

Comment: @tdelaney I run the server using command prompt

Comment: I am so sorry, I had a typo in my code. Thank you for all the help

Comment: You have 2 problems at least. (1) you are using `_start_new_thread` which returns an integer thread id. Its not something you could .send on. use `threading.Thread` instead. Second, you .decode assuming you always have full character boundaries on recv, but you don't. It a byte stream and may break up multicharacter encodings.

Comment: And its not printing any error messages?

Comment: When I run your code and try connecting with your `client.py` code, I see an error message (and that message indicates a problem with your code and the potential solution).

Comment: @tdelaney I fixed the typo but the error message was NameError: name 'clients' is not defined

Comment: I managed to get it to work, thank for you all the help. I am very sorry for the typo in my code.

Comment: I didn't know there is a default on socket initialization my bad

Comment: That list is `client_conns`, not `clients`.

Comment: @X-_-FARZA_D-_-X - The default is `class socket.socket(family=AF_INET, type=SOCK_STREAM, proto=0, fileno=None)` (which has used to annoy me when I worked on non AF_INET protocol networks).

Comment: `data = s.recv(4096).decode()` is a bug. It may fail with UnicodeDecodeError. In that case, you'd have to save the data you have but try an new recv to get the missing encoded bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I featured it out

in your server you have variable client_conns but you add every connection to clients
which is not declared

your client code was pretty much ok in exception of not having exception handling:

also for the line:

```
threading._start_new_thread(handle_client, (conn, address))
```

the function and methods that start with underline character are not meant for usage outside module

also you have to encode data sent between sockets to bytes

the fixed server and client codes are as followed:

server.py:

```
import socket
import threading

host = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
port = 5000
client_conns = []

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((host, port))
s.listen(10)

def broadcast_msg(msg):
    for conn in client_conns:
        conn.send(bytes(msg, 'utf-8'))

def handle_client(conn):
    while True:
        msg = conn.recv(4096).decode()
        broadcast_msg(msg)
        

while True:
    conn, address = s.accept()
    print(f"Connection from: {address}")
    client_conns.append(conn)
    
    threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=[conn]).start()
```

client.py:

```
import socket

def client():
    host = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
    port = 5000

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect((host, port))

    alias = input("Alias: ")

    while True:
        message = input(f"{alias}: ")
        message = alias + ": " + message
        s.send(message.encode())

        data = s.recv(4096).decode()
        print(data)

client()
```